# Is Plasmid pGLO a stable or unstable plasmid varient ?

Tags: microbiology

Is plasmid pGLO a stable or unstable plasmid varient?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: What do you mean by an unstable plasmid?

Comment: The GFP protein is an unstable variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pGLO plasmid uses a stable version of GFP. This is stated in the pGLO education series protocol, and wiki.

I could however, engineer to be unstable if wanted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGLO